# Simple regex-matching

Tags: c#, regex

I have a String

```
String test = @"Lists/Versions/2_.000";
```

I'm a bit confused on how to use regex to do this.

I'm using the pattern

```
String pattern = @"\D+";
```

The msdn page for regular expression says \D is "Matches any character other than a decimal digit"

So shouldn't it be returning 'Lists/Versions/' , '2'?

However its returning

'' , '2', '000'

I would like the string to only match the 2(Or any Integer). How would I do that?

```
String url = @"Lists/Versions/2_.000";
        String pattern = @"\D+";

        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(url, pattern);    
        foreach (string match in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
        }
```

Comment: decimal digits are basically 0-9, regardless of whether there is a dot in front of them... so \D is basically anything that is not a number... including punctuation and letters

Comment: Why would it return two? Also how are you using the Regex? I get `Lists/Versions/` and `_.`

Comment: Please, edit your question to explain in more details what you would like it to match and on what rules.

Comment: you are using a split on non numbers... so your regex is splitting on "Lists/Versions/" and "_." and returning what is before and after those.

Comment: `\D+` is matching every block of things which are not a number and treating those things as the delimiters to split on. The result is an array comprising everything which wasn't matched - the numbers, plus the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your receiving the issue, is because the `/D` is to capture non digits, so it detects two separate numeric values (`2` and `000`) because of the `_`.  So that is how it is grabbing the data.  So you have a couple of choices:

- Break the `string` into manageable portions, then anchor to the array.
- Build a better pattern to separate.

So the question will be, what are you trying to parse? `2.00` ?  Or are you trying to separate numeric numbers in your `string`?

I'm assuming you have a typo also:

- \d   Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9].
- \D   Matches a non-digit character. Equivalent to [^0-9].
- \w   Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to
  "[A-Za-z0-9_]".
- \W   Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to "[^A-Za-z0-9_]".

You should be able to use:

You should simply do the following:

```
string url = @"Lists/Versions/2_.000";
var data = Regex.Split(url, @"\D+");
Console.WriteLine(@"Value: {0} and Secondary Value: {1}", data[0], data[1]);
```

That should find all integer values, so it should provide an output of:

- `2`
- `000`

Which should return as a normal `string []`.  My syntax or expression may be off, but you can find a nice cheat sheet for Regular Expressions [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet).  You'll also want to ensure you check the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BU6gp2

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String url = @"Lists/Versions/2_.000";
        String pattern = @"\D+";

        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(url, pattern);    

        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", substrings[1]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
// using System.Linq;

String url = @"Lists/Versions/2_.000";
String pattern = @"(?<=/)\d+";

string[] substrings = Regex.Matches(url, pattern)
                           .Cast<Match>()
                           .Select(_ => _.Value)
                           .ToArray();    
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need an array.

```
String url = @"Lists/Versions/2_.000";
String pattern = @"(?<=/)\d+";

Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", Regex.Match(url, pattern).Value);
```